# R system() call that accepts prompted responses; to login to VPN

Tags: r

How do I use system() and feed it prompted responses? My responses do not change and so if I can set them once in a txt file or other place that is fine as well.

At the command line, I run the following line to connect to a vpn:

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect web.site.net <<"EOF"
```

and this prompts 5 lines which I respond to and then it logs into the VPN:

```
domain
user
password
exit
EOF
```

When I try to do the same with a system() call in R, I tried this but no joy:

```
system('/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect web.site.net <<"EOF"'; "domain"; "user"; "password"; "exit"; "EOF"')
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can't you just pipe in a file with those inputs instead of using `"EOF"`, e.g, `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect web.site.net < config-file.txt`?

Comment: Thanks nrussell. I get the same error message back:
`>> state: Disconnected
  >> error: Connect not available. Another AnyConnect application is running
or this functionality was not requested by this application.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you can create a file with information you need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209953/connect-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-via-bash).  Then run it from within the R shell by using `system("expect yourFile.sh")`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks polka!  _prepares to dispense product_